# Pull First Key/value in Array with duplicate key names using Kusto in Azure Graph Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I have some tag data in Azure and trying to use Azure Graph Explorer to parse the data. I have tried multiple things but because the key names are duplicated I am having a difficult time finding anything to work to parse data into columns like a normal array or json.  I really only need the first value of displayName. I do not control these key names.  Azure creates these names. I only add the values.

```json
[
   {
      "displayName":"my-app-pr-mg",
      "name":"my-app-pr-mg"
   },
   {
      "displayName":"my-app-mg",
      "name":"my-app-mg"
   },
   {
      "displayName":"Tenant Root Group",
      "name":"1234-567889-8454353-43343"
   }
]
```

I would like only the first displayName value.

I have tried various commands and the closest was mv-expand but I end up with duplicate rows.

I would like first key/value, or somehow make key names different so I could place into unique columns.

1. displayName
2. my-app-pr-mg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like only the first displayName value.

give a column of type `dynamic` named `d`, you could try the following - for accessing the `displayName` property of the first element (index=0) in the array:

`| extend displayName = d[0].displayName`

for example, when run against an azure-data-explorer database:

```
print d = dynamic([{"displayName":"my-app-pr-mg","name":"my-app-pr-mg"},{"displayName":"my-app-mg","name":"my-app-mg"},{"displayName":"Tenant Root Group","name":"1234-567889-8454353-43343"}])
| extend displayName = d[0].displayName
```

| d | displayName |
| --- | --- |
| [ { "displayName": "my-app-pr-mg", "name": "my-app-pr-mg" }, { "displayName": "my-app-mg", "name": "my-app-mg" }, { "displayName": "Tenant Root Group", "name": "1234-567889-8454353-43343" } ] | my-app-pr-mg |

Comment: Thanks! I had to tweak a little but that got it.